# Publishing a paper as an independent researcher, without funds

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, funding, computer-science

I have written a small paper that I have written in the field of computer science. I've had several people read it, and one recommended that it's of enough quality they think I should be able to publish it in a journal. I'd like to explore this option, but almost every reputable journal I can find requires a large sum of money to publish in their journal, which is not an option for me, as I am not affiliated with any institution and cannot spend that amount of money.

Are there any journals in computer science that don't require a large amount of money to publish with? Or will I simply have to do something along the lines of publishing on something akin to arXiv and not continuing past there?

Comment: [tag:independent-researcher]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many journals will forgive page charges for publishing in certain cases, probably cases like yours. I doubt that all will, and you need to ask, but you don't need to ask before you submit the paper. If it passes review and is something they want to publish, staking their own reputation on it, then they might be amenable.

Open access journals are probably less likely to do this, since author fees are the main source of revenue for them, but traditional journals have other revenue sources.

But first, you submit the paper without discussing fees. There is time for that later.

Note, however, that in CS, publishing at conferences is the main venue. But that requires funds for conference attendance and travel.

Comment: I agree, publishing at a conference would be the ideal, but as you've stated, that's just not realistic for me right now. I'll look into negotiating fees with journals, thank you!